# Save terminal output in python during recursive loops

Tags: python, output

I have a python script which is something like the following:

```
def function2(x):
     for j in range(100):
          # long-running computation on x and j

def function1():
     for i in range(100):
         function2(i)
```

I would like to have an ongoing status printed to the terminal which would be something like:

```
Current i: 10
Current j: 31
```

which would update constantly as i and j change. I tried printing with carriage returns, but as soon as the second function starts printing, it erases the output from the first function.

One solution is to just pass `i` to the second function. This would work, but the actual functions are complicated and already take 11 different inputs, so for readability I don't want to add another one. I'm hoping there is a built-in method to do this.

The actual case is a bit more complicated, as the loops are not just for loops over a range, but binary searches. So it's impossible to tell from just a local variable (say, `x`) what the progress is in the binary search. This also makes existing progress bar packages more challenging.

Comment: Use the `ncurses` library so you can directly address different parts of the screen.

Comment: I'd probably use something like `tqdm` and update progress bars manually.

Comment: If you're fine with just one line of output, you can use `sys.stdout.write(f'\r Current i: {x:3}, Current j: {j:3})'`. This doesn't require any external libraries.

Comment: These are great suggestions but don't quite work for my use case. I added some clarifying points (sorry for not posting the full example, but it's a 400-line function).

Comment: @MichaelCao's solution has the last two characters reversed.  It should be `sys.stdout.write(f'\r Current i: {x:3}, Current j: {j:3}')`.  But adding that just after for `for j in range(100):` line in `function2` should do exactly what you want except that it does it on a single line.  I have run it myself and it works.

Comment: The fact that it is difficult to know how many total iterations you might need, as in a binary search for example, doesn't mean you can't report how many steps you have taken in this iteration.  So you can still see the method progressing.  You just can't convert it to a percentage or a `m of n` message.

Comment: if you don't want to send `i` as another parameters then maybe keep it as `global` variable. It is not preferred but it may resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`tqdm` worked.

In my particular case, I was doing a binary search. Thus, I could take the size of the initial interval, the precision cut-off for when the search exits, and the difference in their log base 2 to get the number of iterations. This made tqdm fairly straightforward:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
low_theta = mp.pi / 6
high_theta = mp.pi / 2
theta=low_theta


pbar_length = log2(high_theta - low_theta)
pbar = tqdm(total=int(pbar_length - log2(1e-5)), leave=False, desc = str("Theta ")+str(recursion_depth) + str(" 1st loop"))
while abs(high_theta - low_theta) > 1e-5:
    theta = (high_theta + low_theta)/2
    if costly_subroutine(theta):
        high_theta = theta
    else:
        low_theta = theta
    pbar.update(1)
pbar.close()
```

This shows one very slow-moving progress bar at the top, with a second progress bar underneath. Each time the second progress bar finished, the top one would jump forward.

Comment: this code looks totally different as code in your question. And maybe this was the problem - you show wrong code so we didn't know what is the problem.

Comment: The above code still looks totally different from the code in my actual project! Deciding which parts of the code are necessary to solve a problem, and which are not, remains a hard problem.

Answer (score 0):

The original question asks how you can continually update values on a terminal to report status and specifically calls out they aren't looking for a progress bar.

For this use case, the progress bar library, [Enlighten](https://pypi.org/project/enlighten/) has a [status bar](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#status-bars) capability. These are essentially lines pinned to the bottom of the terminal that can be dynamically updated.

Given the example code, an implementation might look like:

```
import time
import enlighten

manager = enlighten.get_manager()

def function2(x):
    status_bar = manager.status_bar(
        status_format='Current j: {value_j}', value_j='', color='bold_slategray_on_white', leave=False
    )
    for j in range(100):
         status_bar.update(value_j=j)
         time.sleep(.1)  # long-running computation on x and j

    status_bar.close()

def function1():
    status_bar = manager.status_bar(
        status_format='Current i: {value_i}', value_i='', leave=False
    )
    for i in range(100):
         status_bar.update(value_i=i)
         function2(i)

    status_bar.close()

function1()
```

I changed the color on one to show how that would work. Inline colors can also be used and text can be centered or right-justified. See the [docs](https://python-enlighten.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) and examples for more.